# How to read more text in foreach

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I working Yii2 Framework, I want to read more text of each element in foreach . As follows:
My foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($queryUserContractor as $key => $value): ?>
...
<p class="text_content_rating" id="<?= $value->user_id ?>"><?= AcpHelper::shortDesc(RatingContractor::getContentRatingLatestById($value->user_id), 400) ?>
                                                <a class="text_load_more" id="text_load_more">Read more</a></p>
                                            <p class="text_content_rating_full display_none"><?= RatingContractor::getContentRatingLatestById($value->user_id) ?>
                                                <a class="text_hide" id="text_hide">Hide</a></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#text_load_more', function (e) {
        $(".text_content_rating_full").removeClass("display_none");
        $(".text_content_rating").addClass("display_none");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#text_hide', function (e) {
        $(".text_content_rating_full").addClass("display_none");
        $(".text_content_rating").removeClass("display_none");
    });
});
```

My css:

```
p.display_none {
        display: none;
    }
```

Help me, thankall.

Comment: use class selector instead of id, because id is unique on a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give some `outer` div to your elements and then whenever user click on `a` tag check if it has `text_load_more` depending on this add/remove `display_none` class from `p` tags.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.text_load_more ,.text_hide', function(e) {
  var selector = $(this).closest(".outer")
  //check if a has class
  if ($(this).hasClass("text_load_more")) {
    //remove class from full and add class to rating
    selector.find(".text_content_rating_full").removeClass("display_none");
    selector.find(".text_content_rating").addClass("display_none");

  } else {
    selector.find(".text_content_rating_full").addClass("display_none");
    selector.find(".text_content_rating").removeClass("display_none");
  }
});
```

```css
.display_none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added outer div-->
<div class="outer">
  <p class="text_content_rating" id="<?= $value->user_id ?>">abcdclhehclecece
    <a class="text_load_more">Read more</a></p>
  <p class="text_content_rating_full display_none">yxhcgjjechgekjcehk
    <a class="text_hide">Hide</a></p>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <p class="text_content_rating" id="<?= $value->user_id ?>">abcdclhehclecece222
    <a class="text_load_more">Read more</a></p>
  <p class="text_content_rating_full display_none">yxhcgjjechgekjcehk22
    <a class="text_hide">Hide</a></p>
</div>
```